# Magento Widgets not working after upgrade from 1.12 to 1.13 EE

Tags: magento

We have recently upgraded our magento EE to 1.13. It took very long time with 17000 products. However everything is working fine now except the widgets.

When I try to insert a widget to a CMS page it works fine, however in front end it just shows the source code like this:

{{widget type="catalog/product_widget_new" products_count="8" column_count="3" show_title="false" show_addtolinks="false" template="catalog/product/widget/new/content/new_grid.phtml"}}

All files are in place. I suspect that something went wrong with DB structure upgrade.

Any ideas how to fix this.

Regards,

Farrukh Khan